# How to access the Key of an item in lazyColumn or lazyRow?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I am using Jetpack Compose to create a `LazyColumn` as shown below. My lazy list has two differnt view types, for each food in the list, it displays a food name (first type) and a couple of food ingredients (second type).

I am assigning a `Key` to my ingredient items for efficient recomposion purpososes. I was wondering if there is a way for me to get the key that I've assigned to the item inside the body of the item (Like the example below)?

```
   LazyColumn(content = {
        foodList.forEach { food ->

            item {
                Text(text = food.name)
            }

            itemsIndexed(
                items = food.ingredients,
                key = { index, ingredient -> "${index}:${ingredient.url}" }
            ) { index, ingredient ->

                Text(text = ingredient.name)

                // I want to access this item's "Key" here,
                // something like getItemKey()
            }

        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

We get the same `index` and `value` in both `key` and `contentType` lambda as parameters.
We can extract the key creation functionality to a separate method to get the key in both places.

```
itemsIndexed(
    items = food.ingredients,
    key = { index, ingredient -> generateKey(index, ingredient) }
) { index, ingredient ->
    val key = generateKey(index, ingredient)
}

private generateKey(index, ingredient) = "${index}:${ingredient.url}"
```

---

What is the use-case to require the `key` in the `contentType` lambda?

Comment: The idea is the reuse the key which is passed into the ```itemsIndexed`` not to reconstruct the whole thing.

Comment: @rahat, What is the use-case to require the key in the contentType lambda?

Answer (score 1):

We should not be building the key inside the composable, instead, we should have a field inside the item itself.

```
itemsIndexed(
    items = food.ingredients,
    key = { index, ingredient -> ingredient.uniqueValueField }
) { index, ingredient ->
    // key //ingredient.uniqueValueField
}
```

**Reason: The thought process behind this approach is that we do not do processing overhead and/or accidentally trigger recomposition when we do key building during rendering list items.**

*We should always have unique values for the field which will be used as the key.*

**UPDATE**

```
/**
 * The horizontally scrolling list that only composes and lays out the currently visible items.
 * The [content] block defines a DSL which allows you to emit items of different types. For
 * example you can use [LazyListScope.item] to add a single item and [LazyListScope.items] to add
 * a list of items.
 *
 * @sample androidx.compose.foundation.samples.LazyRowSample
 *
 * @param modifier the modifier to apply to this layout
 * @param state the state object to be used to control or observe the list's state
 * @param contentPadding a padding around the whole content. This will add padding for the
 * content after it has been clipped, which is not possible via [modifier] param. You can use it
 * to add a padding before the first item or after the last one. If you want to add a spacing
 * between each item use [horizontalArrangement].
 * @param reverseLayout reverse the direction of scrolling and layout. When `true`, items are
 * laid out in the reverse order and [LazyListState.firstVisibleItemIndex] == 0 means
 * that row is scrolled to the end. Note that [reverseLayout] does not change the behavior of
 * [horizontalArrangement], e.g. with [Arrangement.Start] [123###] becomes [321###].
 * @param horizontalArrangement The horizontal arrangement of the layout's children. This allows
 * to add a spacing between items and specify the arrangement of the items when we have not enough
 * of them to fill the whole minimum size.
 * @param verticalAlignment the vertical alignment applied to the items
 * @param flingBehavior logic describing fling behavior.
 * @param userScrollEnabled whether the scrolling via the user gestures or accessibility actions
 * is allowed. You can still scroll programmatically using the state even when it is disabled.
 * @param content a block which describes the content. Inside this block you can use methods like
 * [LazyListScope.item] to add a single item or [LazyListScope.items] to add a list of items.
 */

inline fun <T> LazyListScope.itemsIndexed(
    items: List<T>,
    noinline key: ((index: Int, item: T) -> Any)? = null,
    crossinline contentType: (index: Int, item: T) -> Any? = { _, _ -> null },
    crossinline itemContent: @Composable LazyItemScope.(index: Int, item: T) -> Unit
)
```

*`contentType` lamda does not essentially need key, you may provide a lambda to return a value which will return the view type, as in `getViewType()` in legacy `RecyclerView`, so that you can reuse the Composable of item.*